# Bitcoin reference code

Tags: bitcoin-gold

I sold Bitcoin using USD wallet and the transaction was completed. I received a reference code but I have no clue on what to do to get the money from what I sold on Bitcoin. How do I get cashed out after I have sold? I'm definitely a novice.

Comment: Sold where/how?

Answer (score 1):

if it was at an atm, and you got given a receipt to redeem. you usually have to wait for a confirmation in which the operating company of that machine will text you when time to redeem or you can keep checking yourself on blockchain.info if it has at least 2 confirmations. once you're ready to redeem, just scan the QR code into the ATM and voila.